# Fabric Crash iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am getting fabric crash on TableView `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Here is a line no. 166 code in my project and code have "Democell" class and cell identifier, so that both value always be there then why crash occurs, I have done much research but still didn't found the reason.

I have call `tablview.reloadData()` the method from 2 places, one is `viewWillAppear` method and also when I am getting response from the server.

## Fabric Crash

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  sRideIphone                    0x100c7d098 DemoTabViewController.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) (DemoTabViewController.swift:166)
1  sRideIphone                    0x100c7d994 @objc DemoTabViewController.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) (<compiler-generated>)
2  UIKitCore                      0x1b4f76a38 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 680
3  UIKitCore                      0x1b4f76f38 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 80
4  UIKitCore                      0x1b4f43740 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2260
5  UIKitCore                      0x1b4f60a60 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 140
6  UIKitCore                      0x1b51e3e54 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1292
7  QuartzCore                     0x18cdea1f0 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 184
8  QuartzCore                     0x18cdef198 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 332
9  QuartzCore                     0x18cd520a8 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 348
10 QuartzCore                     0x18cd80108 CA::Transaction::commit() + 640
11 UIKitCore                      0x1b4d55710 _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 156
12 UIKitCore                      0x1b4e3e1f4 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5604
13 UIKitCore                      0x1b4e3711c __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 152
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1888ee2bc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1888ee23c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
16 CoreFoundation                 0x1888edb24 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 176
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1888e8a60 __CFRunLoopRun + 1004
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1888e8354 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
19 GraphicsServices               0x18aae879c GSEventRunModal + 104
20 UIKitCore                      0x1b4d5bb68 UIApplicationMain + 212
21 sRideIphone                    0x100bcbf60 main (AppDelegate.swift:17)
22 libdyld.dylib                  0x1883ae8e0 start + 4
```

```
let DEMO_CELL_ID = "demoCellID" 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let demoCell:DemoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DEMO_CELL_ID) as! DemoCell // This is line 166
demoCell.selectionStyle = .none
let items = arrSections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
 if items["name"] as! String  == "country"{
      demoCell.lblCountry.isHidden = false
  }

 return demoCell
}
```

i expect to found this crash and resolve.

Comment: if DemoCell  is .xib then have you registered this to tableview?

Comment: Can you share the code for `cellForRow` and point out line no.166?

Comment: Share tableview class code to understand the error

Comment: @MahendraGP DemoCell is not .xib. i have added cell in in storyboard tableview

Comment: @NileshRPatel i have updated code for cellforrowatindex path method.

Comment: @Malik already said this is line no 166 :-  let demoCell:DemoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DEMO_CELL_ID) as! DemoCell

Comment: @princek you are using xib of DemoCell ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

If you are using XIB then register the cell like this

```
self.register(UINib(nibName: "DemoCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DemoCell")
```

and if you create cell directly in storyboard table view cell then register class

```
self.register(DemoCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DemoCell")
```

and set cell identifier is:- DemoCell

```
let DEMO_CELL_ID = "demoCellID" 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let demoCell:DemoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DEMO_CELL_ID) as? DemoCell // This is line 166
demoCell?.selectionStyle = .none
let items = arrSections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
 if items["name"] as! String  == "country"{
      demoCell?.lblCountry.isHidden = false
  }

 return demoCell!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general mistake is that you guarantee a cell object will be returned from .dequeueReusableCell().
It will be most likely if all preconditions are meet, but in your case you get an optional reference. (Consider it as a possible NULL reference if this is new.) Probably does your cell not have the correct ID set in the StoryBoard.

Each Cell in a StoryBoard must know it's identifier, because that identifier is used to look it up. Check if its entered in the properties. (See Screenshot to see where)
[image]

Another pitfall is assuming you get always a cell where the interface tells you its optional. But the Delegate requires you to return allways an object, thus you go and granting it using "!". Most of the time you do get a cell, but typos happen. A good way to work with Swift is to avoid the ! and use the ?.

For instance you could deal with the cell this way:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let demoCell:DemoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DEMO_CELL_ID) as? DemoCell // This is line 166
    demoCell?.selectionStyle = .none
    let items = arrSections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
    if items["name"] as! String  == "country"{
        demoCell?.lblCountry.isHidden = false
    }
    return demoCell ?? UITableViewCell()
}
```

If demoCell is NULL then create an empty basic cell and return it. Not the UI result u want, but also no crash. You can now look why you don't get the cell dequeued as expected. Most of the time getting a cell will be no problem unless something else is wrong.